# How can I set the ID of a browser window?

Tags: electron

Basically, I want to do some communication between 2 ipc renderers. Based on some information in https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/991, I am trying to set the id of a browser window which I'll eventually use to get the browser window and send the events across without involving main.js.

Need to know how i can set the id of a browser window.

I tried the following:

```
chatWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 500, 
    height: 500,
    id: 1234,
});
```

The above didn't work. The following two didn't work either.

```
 chatWindow.id = 1234;
 chatWindow.id(1234);
```

Comment: Even in the github issues you linked there were issues using id. Sending messages between windows in Electron is a pretty manual process. Basically each window needs to be associated with a var in the main process. Then the main process can become a "communication hub" of sorts between windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the `BrowserWindow` id, it's generated by Electron.

Answer (score 1):

The very same issue thread you mentioned also points to [other-window-ipc](https://github.com/greggman/other-window-ipc/), which seems like a great solution to your problem.

Even if you dont want to use yet another library, you'll probably find a pointer to implement the functionality itself within its sources.